# Scripting a batch file for installing network printers

Tags: networking, drivers, batch, printing, printer

I would like to write a batch file to install multiple network printers in our office to a PC. I attempted a file with one printer using the Generic/Text driver and IP address of 192.168.11.70. When I try to run it simply says argument invalid. I verified the file paths for the printer drivers. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
cscript %WINDIR%\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\Prnport.vbs -a -r IP_192.168.100.70 -h 192.168.100.70 -o raw -n 9100
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /ia /m "Generic/Text" /f "C:\prnge001.inf"
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /if /b "Printer2" /f "C:\prnge001.inf" /r "IP_192.168.100.70 /m "Generic/Text"
```

Here is the error message:

[image]

Comment: You need to provide more detail - the code from your batch file would be a necessary start, along with the exact and complete error message you are receiving.

Comment: Thank you for the catch. I thought I had added the code.

Comment: You have mismatched quotation marks in your second `rundll32` command. Please correct all typos (and test!) before submitting questions.

Comment: Which of the 2 `rundll32` lines is throwing the error? Adding a `pause` after the first one will allow you to find out ...

Answer (score 0):

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByhxkwJBdusDczU2MXhrYldfLUU

Its a vbs/wmi script you need to run from an administrative command prompt.

```
cscript printer.vbs -p "Printer Name" -d "HP Universal Printing PS (v6.0.0)" -i "prnhp001.inf" -h "\\<server>\drivers\Printer\prnhp001" -u ad\username -w <password> -s <computer name>
```

I manually took all the necessary scripts from
C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US

And combined the necessary parts to install a printer from scratch including deleting an old printer with the same name.  I then rewrote parts of it to make it even more functional.  The CLI for adding drivers in the MS provided script was terrible and resulted in commands of over 200 characters when using network shares.  So I rewrote the code and streamlined the process.  In addition, if you use the MS default scripts you end up connecting and disconnecting from the same computer 3-5 times when using the provided scripts manually.  This is error prone, and usually the only step that fails it the connect to the remote computer request, at least when I do it, and then you have to redo each command manually at least 2 or 3 times.  The process of re-connecting is also time consuming so my script runs much faster partly due to that.

Comment: Thank you. Is this a startup script?

Comment: @UpNorthGIS add details.  You could make it a script up script, but that is not necessary.  You sit from the chair in your office, and specific the computer name with -s <computer name>.  It attaches via the network to that computer using the credentials provides via -u and -w and install the printer.